# Password validate regex

Tags: regex

im trying to validate passwords on my servlet using the following requirments

o The   password    must    consist of  one number  and one of  the following
special characters: **!@#$%^&*()**

> Note: **1!** and **!1**   are both valid passwords

the regex ive been trying to get to work is

```
?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~-])
```

but it does not take `1!` or `!1`

Comment: try https://regex101.com/r/pB3qE0/1

Answer (score 0):

And why not "simple" like this,

```
/^((?:\d[!@#$%^&*()])|(?:[!@#$%^&*()]\d))$/
```

> **[!@#$%^&*()]**  special characters
>   **\d**            one digit
>   **(?: ...)**      don't capture the group
>   **|**             "Or" operator
>   **^**             (String) Beginning
>   **$**             (String) End

if **only one of these special characters** and **only one number** should match.

mini Javascript Demo:

```js
var items = ["!1","1!","123123","123!","1!2@3"]

for (var idx in items){
  var item = items[idx];
  document.write(item +" => "+ (item.match(/^((?:\d[!@#$%^&*()]){1}|(?:[!@#$%^&*()]\d))$/)||"nomatch"));
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: This is matching `1!2@3`

Comment: now it should match, it was a minor bracket error. :)